# while true: + function + name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, while-loop

this the code .. it started with importing [other packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfF3n.png) :

```
def WHOLE_SMLE():
    try:
        while True:
            Riyadh_city()
            Jiddah_city()
            AHSA_city()
            Buridah_city()
            Madina_city()
            Hail_city()
            Taif_city()
            TABUK_city()
    except (NoSuchElementException, KeyboardInterrupt, Exception ):
        print('ExCEPT errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrror')
        WHOLE_SMLE()
        pass
WHOLE_SMLE()
```

**the project will work in a loop .. But unfortunately it worked only for one time then it will shows this error :**

```
    line 14, in WHOLE_SMLE
    Riyadh_city()
NameError: name 'Riyadh_city' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing the modules (for example `Riyadh`) not the specific functions.

Small example, lets say, that module `Riyadh` includes function `Riyadh_city()`.

```
import Riyadh

# you have to use . operator to use specific function from imported module
Riyadh.Riyadh_city()
```

I recommend you to study more about `import` statement and [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Side note:
Names of the modules should be lowercase, so in case of `Riyadh` name `riyadh` should be preferred (and the module should be stored in `riyadh.py` file).

Comment: thank you mikulatomas, YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER 

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on how those function are defined on the files you are importing and without them we cannot help you so please make a reproducible example.

I assume you may want to call them using the classs name, if they are in a class (e.g. `Taif.Taif_city()` if in `Taif.py` you defined a class `Taif` onto which you have the method `Taif_city()`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH DaSim ❤❤❤❤